# Somehow the last digit of 6x7x8 or 16x17x18 is the same as 3!, can someone prove this pattern for me?

Tags: real-numbers, factorial, products

When trying to find a solution for the problem "Find the last digit of factorial". I encounter this small problem inside a solution on the internet and I can't prove it.

Somehow 6x7x8 (336), 16x17x18 (4896),... have the same last digit as 3! (6). Also 6x7x8x9, 16x17x18x19,.... have the same last digit as 4!. Same with 6x7 and 2!. We will omit the case of 1! and 6 or 16 since the last digit of the product of 6 and any even number will always be the same as the last digit of that number (6x2 = 12, 6x4 = 24, 6x18 = 108) (please note that the number before in the solution I mention is always even, so let's skip this 1! and 6 cases)

I can easily prove for 4! and 11x12x13x14 or 3! and 21x22x23 has the same last digit, since we removed the number 5 and 0, the last digit of the result is always the product of the last digits of the components.

Now I only need to prove 2! 3! 4! have the same last digit as 6x7 6x7x8 6x7x8x9, then of course it will apply for any number behind.

The [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/last-non-zero-digit-factorial/) of solution for anyone who needed. Actually, I want to understand why the last digit of n! is the same as 2^a x a! x b! while a is floor(n/5), b is n mod 5. I understand the 2^a x a! part, the n mod 5 (b!) part is the "small problem" I'm talking about and I need to prove the above to complete understanding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you multiply 6 by a number ending with 6 the result will end with 6, because $6 \times 6=36$.

Comment: Apparently you mean the last non-zero digit of a factorial, not the last digit? It's trivial to prove $2! \equiv 6\times 7 \pmod{10}$ and $3! \equiv 6 \times 7 \times 8 \pmod{10}$ and $4! \equiv 6 \times 7 \times 8 \times 9 \pmod{10}$: just write out the actual numbers.

Comment: @ashepler I could be mistaken, but I think that the question being asked is the *trivial* one.  To the OP: it is not tough to prove that if $a_1 \equiv b_1 \pmod{10}, a_2 \equiv b_2 \pmod{10}, \cdots, a_k \equiv b_k \pmod{10},$ where $~a_1, \cdots, a_k, b_1, \cdots, b_k \in \Bbb{Z^+},$ then $$\left[\prod_{i=1}^k a_k\right] \equiv \left[\prod_{i=1}^k b_k\right] \pmod{10}.$$

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I don't think about just writing it out lol. Yes, it's just 2!≡6×7(mod10) and 3!≡6×7×8(mod10) and  4!≡6×7×8×9(mod10) like @aschepler said and I don't need to prove anything here.. I'm so dumb my question is like why the last digit of 12 is the same as 22. Sorry.